# Better way to set a nested object property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I am currently using elasticsearch and need to set some deeply nested properties on my object, currently I am setting them like this:

```
this.queryDSL.body.filter = {};
this.queryDSL.body.filter.bool = {};
this.queryDSL.body.filter.bool.must = [];
```

An iterative way, building up the empty properties and appending on them. I tried setting it all at once like this:

```
this.queryDSL.body.filter.bool.must = []
```

This results in an error since javascript doesn't create the bool values in between, in the form of undefined errors.

Is my way ok or is there a far better way of doing this? Preferably I would like to set them all at once like in my 2nd example.

Comment: The main problem with the second example is that JS can't guess what `bool` should be.  I would stick with the first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example works and there's really nothing wrong with it. You can also do it like:

```
this.queryDSL.body.filter = {
    bool: {
        must: [

        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: True it's just a little much typing and I need to optionally set another property on the same level so I need to be specific. Otherwise I might reset some object values. I was just hoping for something a bit cleaner. Thanks though!